# C++ Qt inherit from custom widget

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qpushbutton

I'm working on a project with Qt and C++.
Now my Question is:

**Is inheritance possible in UI classes?**

For example: This is the Widget I want to inherit from

```
//windowA.h
namespace Ui {
    class WindowA;
}

class WindowA : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit WindowA(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~AddWindow();

    QPushButton *button; 
};

//windowA.cpp
WindowA::WindowA(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    button = new QPushButton();
    button->setText("Save");
    connect(button, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT (//slot));

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();

    layout->addWidget(button, 0, 0);

    this->setLayout(layout);
}
```

This is the widget that inherits from `WindowA`

```
//windowB.h
namespace Ui {
    class WindowB;
}

class WindowB : public WindowA
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit WindowB(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~WindowB();
};
```

How would I implement a QPushButton, so that it's possible to set different text in both classes?

I can add a QPushButton but the text set in `WindowA` would also be set in `WindowB`. The problem is to set a different text for the button in `WindowB` than it is set for the button in `WindowA`

Comment: *"I can add a QPushButton but the text set in `WindowA` would also be set in `WindowB`."*  - Yes, that's what inheritance means. WindowB IS A WindowA. I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: @JarMan but how can I change the text of the Button in `WindowB` so that it's different than in `WindowA`?

Comment: Where does your text get set?

Comment: @JarMan I updated the code example above, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need to do is change what text you set on the button in your constructor:

```
WindowB::WindowB(QWidget *parent) :
    WindowA(parent)
{
    button->setText("Something else!");
}
```

Comment: No redeclaration of `button` in `WindowB`? No `button = new QPushButton`?

Comment: You must be new to C++. WindowB already has declared `button` because it IS a WindowA. (See how it calls the WindowA constructor?) If you add `button = new QPushButton` again, you will be overwriting the existing button and leaking memory.

Comment: Well, I tested it and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: And yes, I am pretty new to C++, but I keep learning.